# How do you Handle a TimeoutException when calling WebServices using the SoapClient in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, web-services, soap-client, timeoutexception

How do you handle a TimeoutException that is generated when calling WebServices using the SoapClient?

There doesn't seem to be any event to be handled in order to catch any Exceptions generated when calling web services.

Is it possible to catch any Exceptions thrown, especially the TimeoutException??

I also posted this question to the Silverlight.net forums: http://silverlight.net/forums/p/46029/124010.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, [NO](http://silverlight.net/forums/p/46029/124010.aspx). There is no way to handle any Exceptions thrown when invoking Web Service Methods in Silverlight 2. Unless of course you create your own modified version of the SoapClient that Visual Studio auto-generates for you. This is a Terrible Design Flaw!!

Comment: Is this still true in Silverlight 3?

Comment: Good question, I am facing that problem now.